# When to use supervisor actor?

Tags: akka, akka-http

- When should I create supervisor actors?
- By default the actors are restarted when crashed and that is exactly how I want it. Should I create a supervisor actor in this case?
- Should I create a supervisor actor for an actor whose sole purpose is to read from a db table?
- What if the actor is making a rest call? Should it have a supervisor?

Comment: You can find answers to last 2 questions on SO. When it comes to supervision, probably the [official doc](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/general/supervision.html) is the best resource. Note that all actors are supervisors for their children. Probably by "supervisor actor" you mean an actor whose sole purpose is supervising its children. If that's the case, it is a common pattern but normally along with accepting/forwarding messages to/from children. If the default strategy is a fit for your use case there's no need to worry about the supervision, as you can always change it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Your two last points are a nice use case for supervisor actors. Imagine this scenario, you lose connection with your database which is a common case in cloud environments.

If you don't use a supervisor your actors will keep restarting and calling to the database until the connection is reestablished.

With the supervisor we can be smarter, if we got a connection error we can kill all the children and fail fast for every arriving request (circuit breaker). At the same time, we can check the database connection from time to time, eventually the connection will come back and the supervisor will spread all the database actors again.